# Translate CSS to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I current have this code:

```
.mr15 > *
  margin-right: 15px
  &:last-child
    margin-right: 0
```

How can I translate it to Javascript? And should I use JQuery or pure Javascript for this case? Thank you.

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean with translating CSS to JS. They are not equivalent. Do you mean you want to set inline styles with JS using the rule in your post?

Comment: Is this native CSS?

Comment: You can't translate CSS to javascript. You can use javascript to apply certain CSS to elements or create a stylesheet via JS at runtime. You should update your question with what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this case you can use both pure JavaScript and jQuery,
this jQuery version:

```
$(".mr15").children().css({"margin-right": "15px"});
$(".mr15:last-child").css({" margin-right", 0});
```

Comment: Why would he do that instead of using plain css? Not that your answer is "wrong" but it's not really helpful (no answer would be at this point)

Comment: I think he need js version of current CSS, in normal mode he must use CSS, but in some cases you may need jQuery. @lexith